# Error de conversion de tipo de datos fecha editando un smallint

Tags: sql-server, conversión-de-tipos

Buenas he restaurado una base de datos en local para hacer unas pruebas e intentando actualizar un campo de una de las tablas, me retorna este error:

> La conversión del tipo de datos varchar en datetime produjo un valor
> fuera de intervalo.

Pero el campo que estoy editando, no es de tipo fecha, es un `smallint`
La consulta no tiene nada de especial:

```
UPDATE Articulos SET publicar =1 Where CPArticulo ="034_pd"
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?
Gracias.

Comment: El error pareciera que está en que `CPArticulo` que pareciera ser `datetime` y obviamente `034_pd` no es es convertible en una fecha. Al menos eso es lo que se deduce, del código y del error.

Comment: `CPArticulo` es `Varchar(20)`

Comment: Entonces no veo la forma en que el error coincida con el código que estás mostrando. A menos que venga de algún otro código "oculto" en un trigger